# Using SparseTensor with reinitializable iterator doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Using Tensorflow 1.10.1 with Python 3.5.2

I've got a tf.SparseTensor object, created from a set of index tuples, all with value 1, and I've made a Dataset as such

```
data = SparseTensor(indices = tuples, values= np.ones(len(tuples)), 
    dense_shape=[n_users, n_items])
```

Then I've created an iterator from it

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
```

And I've initialized the iterator

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, 
    dataset.output_shapes, None, dataset.output_classes)
training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

And I've defined a network very simply as

```
input_data = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(next_element)
h = tf.layers.dense(input_data, 50)
```

When I try to pass the dataset through the network by calling

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
        tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    sess.run([h])
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
h = tf.layers.dense(input_data, 50)
File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 189, in dense
    return layer.apply(inputs)
File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 805, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 362, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 720, in __call__
    self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1440, in _assert_input_compatibility
    str(x.shape.as_list()))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]
```

I also noticed that the dataset's next element is missing dimensions for the number of columns. Before passing through the iterator calling:

```
    print(data)
    print(data.get_shape())
    print(data.dense_shape)
```

gets me

```
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("SparseTensor/indices:0", shape=(2451491,2), dtype=int64), 
    values=Tensor("SparseTensor/values:0", shape=(2451491,), dtype=float64), 
    dense_shape=Tensor("SparseTensor/dense_shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
(50213, 32392)
Tensor("SparseTensor/dense_shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
```

if I call the same on the next element by calling:

```
    print(next_element)
    print(next_element.get_shape())
    print(next_element.dense_shape)
```

I get back

```
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=int64), 
    values=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:1", shape=(?,), dtype=float64),
    dense_shape=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:2", shape=(1,), dtype=int64))
(?,)
Tensor("DeserializeSparse:2", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the get_next() on the dataset gets you tensors for one row of the sparse tensor. You can add `dataset = dataset.batch(1)` to your code so you'll get the rows in the right dimensions as then the dataset would produce a list that has the one row (sth like returning shape [1,X] instead of [X,])